# How to detect unvisited pages of my wordpress website

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a wordpress website with several categories and I am going to redesign my website. I would like to know which categories are visited and which are not, can you tell me how to do that? Is there any plugin for that? Or maybe do I have to code this part in PHP, if that's the case, can you please tell me how to do that?

Thanx in advance

Comment: You could add Google Analytics or any other analytics package.

Comment: Create an array, set it as a session, add to the array for each page visit dependent on the page.  That's a quick solution.

Comment: Noah's comment won't work, as it would be user based. The OP is wanting to find out which pages aren't visited by ANY visitor.